# Visual Studio 2019/SSAS cannot connect to database server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas

I'm new to Visual Studio and SSAS..

I've have installed Visual Studio 2019 (Community) with SSAS on my local machine. I'm able to connect to local database server (SQL Server 2019) for creating Data Source Views and Cubes. However when I try to Browse the created cube I get error message below.

> A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2383 (System)

What I don't get why can I create Data Source Views and Cubes using the database, but I can't run the browser!??

Comment: The obvious question would be, have you checked that the Analysis Services service is running? The error suggests it is not.

Comment: Hi Larnu. How do I check that? I woud assume it runs as I was able to create a Cube..

Comment: Check either in the SQL Server Configuration Manager or in the Services Manager. The service does *not* need to be running for you to create cubes in SSAS because it doesn't use said service. It's when you deploy/connect to the service you need it.

Comment: Aha I see. Thanks. It's not running. Now, how do I get it running?

Comment: {Right Click} -> `Start` (normally).

Comment: Thx. I hadn't installed the feature within SQL Server and hence couldn't start as well. Now I have it up and running :-)